# authentication for specific routes in passport

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js

authentication for specific routes in passport

Is there a way by which I can unauthenticate specific routes say if I want to unauthenticate `/seller` page..

Please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could potentially log users out when they navigate to that page using `req.logout`.

Example:

```js
app.get('/seller', (req, res) => {
  req.logout();
}, (req, res) => {
  // seller page logic
});
```

If you want the users to stay logged in for other pages then I would recommend instead creating an authorization middleware so only specific users would see the `seller` page.

Brief example:

```js
const authorize = (req, res, next) => {
  const { user } = req;
    if (user && user.loggedIn && user.admin) {
      // Allow access
      return next();
    }
};
```